# UrlRewriter.net problem with master page

Tags: .net, asp.net, url, url-rewriting, mod-rewrite

i have implemented Intelligencia.UrlRewriter im my masterpage site.

I am successfully able to redirect the page.

but on the virtual path its not able to find the CSS/javascript file.

Also its not able to find when i user url like  http://localhost/mywebsite/test/ but it works when i use  http://localhost/mywebsite/test

my rule is as following

```
<rewrite url="^.*-c([0-9]+).html/?$" to="~/ProductsByCategory.aspx?cid=$1" processing="stop" />
    <rewrite url="^.*-p([0-9]+)/?$" to="~/ProductDetails.aspx?pid=$1" processing="stop" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it working  after using resolveurl as following.
I found solution at http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2008/06/master-page-image-display-problem-and.html

Thanks

```
<img src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~")%>Images/Logo.gif"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

your path should be look like, use ~ sign to map server path

```
<link href="~/App_Themes/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**Edit:**
In web.config where you putting URL-rewrite rule, put rule for js and css files like

```
<add name="indexJS" virtualUrl="^~/(.*)/(.*)/(.*).js"    rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" destinationUrl="~/js/$3.js" ignoreCase="true" />
```

**Note:** 
Rule is not exactly, I have implement different dll, you can change your accordingly

Comment: Thanks Muhammad.

but please can you explain little bit more? where to add the js rule?

Comment: In your web.config, where you have already define other rules, put these as well for js and css files